# Testing a vscode extension that depends on another one

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, python-extensions

I'm trying to write a test for an extension. The extension uses the python extension (ms-python.python).
Therefore I put this in my package.json:

```
"extensionDependencies": [
    "ms-python.python"
],
```

To be able to run my test I need "ms-python.python" to be installed. I followed this documentation:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension#custom-setup-with-vscodetestelectron

but for some reason I can't make it work.
When running my test with 'npm run test':

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as cp from 'child_process';
import { downloadAndUnzipVSCode, resolveCliPathFromVSCodeExecutablePath, runTests } from '@vscode/test-electron';
import * as fs from 'fs-extra';
import * as rimraf from 'rimraf';


async function main() {

    const tmpHomeDir: string = fs.mkdtempSync("/tmp/vscode-tests");
    try {
        const workspaceSettingsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/test/compile/workspace/.vscode/settings.json');
        await fs.ensureFile(workspaceSettingsPath);

        // The folder containing the Extension Manifest package.json
        // Passed to `--extensionDevelopmentPath`
        const extensionDevelopmentPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');

        const vscodeExecutablePath = await downloadAndUnzipVSCode('1.50.0');
        const cliPath = resolveCliPathFromVSCodeExecutablePath(vscodeExecutablePath);
        cp.spawnSync(cliPath, ['--install-extension', 'ms-python.python'], {
            encoding: 'utf-8',
            stdio: 'inherit'
        });

        await runTests({
            vscodeExecutablePath,
            extensionDevelopmentPath: extensionDevelopmentPath,
            extensionTestsPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './compile/index'),
            launchArgs: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/test/compile/workspace')],
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to run tests: ' + err);
        process.exit(1);
    } finally {
        rimraf.sync(tmpHomeDir);
    }
}

main();
```

This start a new vscode(Extension Development Host)but with a message saying:

> Cannot activate the 'xxx' extension because it depends on the 'Python'
> extension, which is not installed. Would you like to install the
> extension and reload the window?

So it seems the Python extension was not installed, or not where it should...

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/different-ways-to-create-vscode-extension-dependencies/ Please read "Recommendation in Code" section. You shouldn't call `spawnSync`, as VSCode API allows you to install an extension in TypeScript directly.

Comment: I have the same issue. while my extension doesn't have a dependency on another extension, my tests do, and in fact, my tests have same dependency as you  "ms-python.python".